# Automatically restarting IIS7

Tags: iis-7

I want to know all possibilities that IIS7 application pool automatically restart.
Because I'm facing such situation and i have no idea about what should i looking for.

Comment: You want to *make* it restart automatically, or it *is* restarting automatically and you want to figure out *why*? Regardless, listing "all possibilities" doesn't seem like a particularly productive pursuit. Update your question to include more details and context if you expect a quality answer.

Comment: Click on Edit Application Pool/Recycling and look at the options that were selected

Comment: It's like this asp.net application we are using get blackout as application pool get automatically restarted.So I need to know what could be the reason for this.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of reasons that an IIS app pool may restart. The best resource I've found was a blog post [ASP.NET Case Study: Lost session variables and appdomain recycles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/08/02/asp-net-case-study-lost-session-variables-and-appdomain-recycles.aspx), by Tess Ferrandez that goes into detail on how to identify the issue and fix it. She lists the following reasons that an app domain will recycle:

> An application domain will unload when any one of the following occurs:
>
> - Machine.Config, Web.Config or Global.asax are modified
> - The bin directory or its contents is modified
> - The number of re-compilations (aspx, ascx or asax) exceeds the limit specified by the  setting in machine.config or web.config (by default this is set to 15)
> - The physical path of the virtual directory is modified
> - The CAS policy is modified
> - The web service is restarted (2.0 only)
> - Application Sub-Directories are deleted (see Todd’s blog  http://blogs.msdn.com/toddca/archive/2006/07/17/668412.aspx for more
>     info)

Comment: Thanks, What if there is select and update transaction inside same default TransactionScope constructor which is repetitively invoked within a foreach loop.

Comment: I don't know about that, but if the code throws an uncatchable exception (like a StackOverflowException) it will cause your entire app pool to restart, even if you have a global error handler.

Comment: What are these uncatchable exceptions? What are the reasons for these exceptions?

Comment: Some .NET exceptions aren't catchable and will terminate your process. From MSDN: "Starting with the .NET Framework version 2.0, a StackOverflowException object cannot be caught by a try-catch block and the corresponding process is terminated by default." Given the limited information you've provided I can't really help you any further, as I have no idea if this is even applicable to your problem.

Comment: Actually i dont have much information,one thing that we found was infinite loop cause this problem but that was not all there must be something else,so i just want know what should be my main focus?

Comment: There should be an exception logged in the Windows event log if the process is crashing. I would also setup WinDbg to take a crash dump the next time the IIS process terminates unexpectedly. With a crash dump you should be able to find the root cause. If you're not familiar with debugging crash dumps then contact MS support, they can often help by looking at a crash dump of your application.

Comment: Sneal that is something new, yup we studied event log but not much help was there,i l look into that crash dump debugging and get back to you.